# Discriminated/disjoint unions in Flow

Tags: flowtype

[image: Sample errors]

I'm trying to make [Flow](https://flow.org/blog/2015/07/03/Disjoint-Unions/) happy.

It's not very, giving me this:

```
app/components/commands/types.js:117
117:   { state: 'state-retries-timeout',
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ string literal `state-retries-timeout`. Expected string literal `state-initial`, got `state-retries-timeout` instead
 60:   { state: 'state-initial', touched: boolean }
```

But I don't see how I'm not following the [documentation](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#disjoint-unions-with-exact-types-a-classtoc-idtoc-disjoint-unions-with-exact-types-hreftoc-disjoint-unions-with-exact-typesa)

Source code:

```
// @flow

/**
 * A server-side validation message. Should contain a globally unique key
 * and a message. The key can be used for internationalisation purposes.
 */
export type ValidationMessage =
  { key: string,
    message: string }

export function validationMessage(key: string, message: string): ValidationMessage {
  return { key, message }
}

/**
 * The field is untouched in this user-session.
 */
export const StateInitial = 'state-initial';

/**
 * The edit is not yet persisted anywhere.
 */
export const StatePending = 'state-pending'
/**
 * The command is not yet committed on the server, but is committed locally.
 */
export const StatePendingSavedLocally = 'state-pending-saved-locally'
/**
 * The command was successfully commited.
 */
export const StateSuccess = 'state-success'
/**
 * The command was commited, but there are resulting warnings.
 */
export const StateSuccessWarnings  = 'state-success-warnings'
/**
 * The command or its data was invalid and the server returned 400 Bad Request;
 * it may not be retried without changing it.
 */
export const StateRejected = 'state-rejected'

/**
 * Despite numerous retries, the app failed to persist the change to the server.
 */
export const StateRetriesTimeout = 'state-retries-timeout'

export type Initial =
  { state: 'state-initial',
    touched: boolean }

export type Pending =
  { state: 'state-pending',
    touched: boolean }

export type PendingSavedLocally =
  { state: 'state-pending-saved-locally',
    touched: boolean }

export type Success =
  { state: 'state-success',
    touched: boolean }

export type SuccessWarnings =
  { state: 'state-success-warnings',
    warnings: ValidationMessage[],
    touched: boolean }

export type Rejected =
  { state: 'state-rejected',
    errors: ValidationMessage[],
    touched: boolean }

export type RetriesTimeout =
  { state: 'state-retries-timeout',
    touched: boolean }

/**
 * The discriminated union of all states we allow fields to be represented as.
 */
export type ValueChangeState =
  | Initial
  | Pending
  | PendingSavedLocally
  | Success
  | SuccessWarnings
  | Rejected
  | RetriesTimeout

export const initial: ValueChangeState  =
  { state: 'state-initial',
    touched: false }

export const pending: ValueChangeState =
  { state: 'state-pending',
    touched: true }

export const pendingSavedLocally: ValueChangeState =
  { state: 'state-pending-saved-locally',
    touched: true }

export const success: ValueChangeState =
  { state: 'state-success',
    touched: true }

export function successWarnings(warnings: ValidationMessage[], touched: boolean = true): ValueChangeState {
  return {
    state: 'state-success-warnings',
    warnings,
    touched
  }
}

export function rejected(errors: ValidationMessage[], touched: boolean = true): ValueChangeState {
  return {
    state: 'state-rejected',
    errors,
    touched
  }
}

export const retriesTimeout: ValueChangeState =
  { state: 'state-retries-timeout',
    touched: true }
```

Sample usage

```
// @flow
/*eslint no-unused-expressions: 0 */
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { describe, it } from 'mocha';
import { initial, pending } from './types';
import { valueStateReducer } from './reducers';
import { successOf, rejectionOf, timeoutOf, successWarningsOf } from './actions';

describe('(Reducer) components/commands', function() {
  describe('valueStateReducer', function() {
    const noop = () => ({ type: 'NOOP' });
    const testing = () => ({ type: 'commands/TESTING' });
    const subject = valueStateReducer('commands/TESTING');

    it('other makes no change', function() {
      const res = subject(initial, noop());
      expect(res).to.deep.eq(initial);
    });

    it('of action makes pending', function() {
      const res = subject(initial, testing());
      expect(res).to.deep.eq(pending);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Your screenshot does not show where you define or use the disjoint union. Can you provide another example in plaintext, preferably stand-alone, that outlines the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: @RossSolomon Done; added the file and some example usage in a unit test. No I can't isolate it; it happens INSIDE our code base, not outside of it, even when fed this file as a stand-alone file.

Comment: You'll need to provide a way for me to reproduce the error, but pasting that code into flow.org/try passes flow checks just fine.

Comment: I recommend commenting out every usage of this union until you've narrowed it down to the one area that causes the error.

Comment: That's possible, but what you're recommending affects the entire code-base, since we've threaded this type throughout. It's not done in a jiffy.

Comment: There's unfortunately no way anyone will be able to help you if you don't provide a repro case.

Comment: @RossSolomon You could have me enable logging, like it normal in production settings? Or have the type checker output a description of why it considers the types flawed? I'm just not able to reproduce it outside of the project.

Comment: Ping -----------------

Comment: To see a trace, you can run `flow check --traces 10` and decipher the output. Somewhere you have code that is using one of these cases when it has the other. If you are willing to svreenshare, I am happy to walk through it with you to debug.

Comment: Thank you Adam, having had the trace output would probably have enabled me to solve this problem earlier, since I assume it would have shown all points where the type is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that flow doesn't properly handle destructive assignment of nullable/undefined discriminated union/sum types when also providing a default value.

[image: assignment bug]

In this screenshot I default `valueState` to `initial` (one of the DU cases). This triggers the bug.

If I instead default further down, flow doesn't barf:

[image: bug workaround]